# Use color map from seaborn sns.pairplot tab10_r on mpl_toolkits 3D scatter plot

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn, scatter3d

I am trying to get the first two colors found in the `sns.pairplot` shown here using

```
colors = dict(zip(['2', '1', '0'], sns.color_palette('tab10_r', 3)))
```

[image]

on the 3D scatter plot using mpl_toolkits.  When I put the `tab10_r` into the `cmap`, I get this output:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d


fig = plt.figure()
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 12))
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")

x= x_pca[:,0]
y= x_pca[:,1]
z = x_pca[:,2]


y_train_new = y_train_orig.argmax(1)

ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, c = y_train_new, marker = 'o', alpha=0.6, s=55, cmap='tab10_r', edgecolor='k')
plt.title("3D Scatterplot: 95% of the variability captured", pad = 15)
ax.set_xlabel('First principal component')
ax.set_ylabel('Second principal component')
ax.set_zlabel('Third principal component')
```

Here is some data:

| x | y | z | not used | Label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -3.8481877 | -0.47685334 | 0.63422906 | 1.0396314 | 1 |
| -2.320888 | 0.65347993 | 1.1519914 | 0.12997247 | 1 |
| 1.5827686 | 1.4119303 | -1.7410104 | -4.6962333 | 1 |
| -0.1337152 | 0.13315737 | -1.6648949 | -1.4205348 | 1 |
| -0.4028037 | 1.332986 | 1.3618442 | 0.3292255 | 1 |
| -0.015517877 | 1.346349 | 1.4083523 | 0.87017965 | 1 |
| -0.2669228 | 0.5478992 | -0.06730786 | -1.5959451 | 1 |
| -0.03318152 | 0.3263167 | -2.116833 | -5.4616213 | 1 |
| 0.4588691 | 0.6723614 | -1.617398 | -4.3511734 | 1 |
| 0.5899199 | 0.66525555 | -1.694493 | -3.9452586 | 1 |
| 1.610061 | 2.4186094 | 1.8807093 | 1.3764497 | 0 |
| 1.7985699 | 2.4387648 | 1.6306056 | 1.1184534 | 0 |
| -9.222036 | -9.9776 | -9.832 | -9.909746 | 0 |
| 0.21364458 | -1.0171559 | -4.9093766 | -6.2154694 | 0 |
| -0.019955145 | -1.1677283 | -4.6549516 | -5.9503417 | 0 |
| 0.44730473 | -0.77167743 | -4.7527356 | -5.971007 | 0 |
| -0.16508447 | -0.005777468 | -1.5020386 | -4.49326 | 0 |
| -0.8654994 | -0.54387957 | -1.300646 | -4.621529 | 0 |
| -1.7471086 | -2.0005553 | -1.7533782 | -2.6065414 | 0 |
| -1.5313624 | -1.6995796 | -1.4394685 | -2.600004 | 0 |

How to go about getting the the colors from the `seaborn` plots onto the 3D scatter plot?

Comment: Hi @joe - the `pairplot` has 3 categories, while `3D scatter plot` appears to have just 2. Are there 3 categories and the data is not included? If I add a `2` for some labels, the colors appear similar to pairplot... is that what you are looking to achieve?

Comment: Hello @Redox, the `pairplot` actually has 2 categories.  I put 3 in the `seaborn` plot code in order to get those colors, but that was the actual data I used.  If I left the `seaborn` code with just 2 categories, I would get grey and purple.  Hope this explanation helps.  Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Redox, I just re-read your initial comment, yes, the colors I guess will appear similar to the `pairplot` if I add another label, however, the new data that I am using only has 2 labels, 0 and 1.  I 'tricked' the `seaborn` plot into thinking that was 3 classes by adding `3` to the initial `seaborn` code.  How can I do that then for the 3D scatter plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification. From your comments, I believe you want to use the **green** and **purple** colors available in `tab10_r`, which would automatically get picked up if you had 3 categories.

I think you have already know most of the answer. From the code around `pairplot` creation, you already know how to get the dictionary with the rgb values. Use it to get the two rgb colors you need....

```
colors = dict(zip(['2', '1', '0'], sns.color_palette('tab10_r', 3))) #Your code
new_colors = list(colors.values()) #Get the rgb values for 3 colors into a list
del new_colors[0] #Remove first color - Grey
```

Once you have the list, you can use `ListedColormap()` to create your own cmap and use it.... (updated code - replace your `ax.scatter()` with this)

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
mycmap = ListedColormap(new_colors)

ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, c = y_train_new, marker = 'o', alpha=1, s=85, edgecolor='k', cmap=mycmap)#'tab10_r', )
```

**Output**

[image]