# Add legend to mplot3d

Tags: python-3.x, legend, scatter3d

For the 3D plot given here (thanks to [Redox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16404872/redox) for his [elegant solution posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72886844/use-color-map-from-seaborn-sns-pairplot-tab10-r-on-mpl-toolkits-3d-scatter-plot)):

[image]

how to go about adding the legend?  I tried `ax.legend()` but got the message `No artists with labels found to put in legend.  Note that artists whose label start with an underscore are ignored when legend() is called with no argument.`

Can you assist me in adding the legend to this 3D plot.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

colors = dict(zip(['2', '1', '0'], sns.color_palette('tab10_r', 3))) #Your code
new_colors = list(colors.values()) #Get the rgb values for 3 colors into a list
del new_colors[0] #Remove first color - Grey

fig = plt.figure()
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 12))
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")

x= x_pca[:,0]
y= x_pca[:,1]
z = x_pca[:,2]


y_train_new = y_train_orig.argmax(1)

ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, c = y_train_new, marker = 'o', alpha=0.6, s=55, cmap=mycmap, edgecolor='k')
plt.title("3D Scatterplot: 95% of the variability captured", pad = 15)
ax.set_xlabel('First principal component')
ax.set_ylabel('Second principal component')
ax.set_zlabel('Third principal component')
```

Data:

| x | y | z | not used | Label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -3.8481877 | -0.47685334 | 0.63422906 | 1.0396314 | 1 |
| -2.320888 | 0.65347993 | 1.1519914 | 0.12997247 | 1 |
| 1.5827686 | 1.4119303 | -1.7410104 | -4.6962333 | 1 |
| -0.1337152 | 0.13315737 | -1.6648949 | -1.4205348 | 1 |
| -0.4028037 | 1.332986 | 1.3618442 | 0.3292255 | 1 |
| -0.015517877 | 1.346349 | 1.4083523 | 0.87017965 | 1 |
| -0.2669228 | 0.5478992 | -0.06730786 | -1.5959451 | 1 |
| -0.03318152 | 0.3263167 | -2.116833 | -5.4616213 | 1 |
| 0.4588691 | 0.6723614 | -1.617398 | -4.3511734 | 1 |
| 0.5899199 | 0.66525555 | -1.694493 | -3.9452586 | 1 |
| 1.610061 | 2.4186094 | 1.8807093 | 1.3764497 | 0 |
| 1.7985699 | 2.4387648 | 1.6306056 | 1.1184534 | 0 |
| -9.222036 | -9.9776 | -9.832 | -9.909746 | 0 |
| 0.21364458 | -1.0171559 | -4.9093766 | -6.2154694 | 0 |
| -0.019955145 | -1.1677283 | -4.6549516 | -5.9503417 | 0 |
| 0.44730473 | -0.77167743 | -4.7527356 | -5.971007 | 0 |
| -0.16508447 | -0.005777468 | -1.5020386 | -4.49326 | 0 |
| -0.8654994 | -0.54387957 | -1.300646 | -4.621529 | 0 |
| -1.7471086 | -2.0005553 | -1.7533782 | -2.6065414 | 0 |
| -1.5313624 | -1.6995796 | -1.4394685 | -2.600004 | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add these lines at the end of your code to add and adjust the legend. Do take a look if the 0 and 1 match to the purple and green as I have added them manually.
You can adjust the position of the box by using `bbox_to_anchor`, the font and text of the title and legend items, size of the dots, etc. by using this. The colors are picked up from the `new_colors` that was created earlier, but you can change it to anything you want. Let me know in case of any questions...

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
myHandle = [Line2D([], [], marker='.', color=new_colors[0], markersize=20, linestyle='None'),
          Line2D([], [], marker='.', color=new_colors[1], markersize=20, linestyle='None')]
legend = ax.legend(handles = myHandle, labels=['1', '0'], loc="upper right", title="My Title", bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.0), title_fontsize=20, prop={'size': 10})
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response.  I am getting the error message, "`NameError: name 'Line2D' is not defined`.

Comment: Missed to add library... pls add `from matplotlib.lines import Line2D`